# ImportError: cannot import name 'Torus' from 'torus'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I have a code that I want to run and receive the result, but the problem is when I run the code, I will find this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Torus' from 'torus'
```

I don't know where the problem is. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is my code :

```
from torus import Torus
values = [
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1],
]
m, n = 2, 2
torus = Torus(values, m, n, 'storage.txt')
torus.make()
torus.save('output-3x2.png', square_size=24)
```

Comment: please let me know if you need to check refactor code.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: can you provide the torus package doucment or website or git repo

Comment: For sure this is the link: https://github.com/man4/debruijn-torus

Comment: @KlausD. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\New VS Code\app.py", line 311, in <module>
    from torus import torus
ImportError: cannot import name 'torus' from 'torus' (C:\Users\Mahmoud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torus\__init__.py)
PS D:\New VS Code>  This is the error

Answer (score 0):

you need to install torus for importing it
go to thd console and write this

```
pip install Torus
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did install but I have the same problem!!